# Gitlab CI Symfony : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, symfony, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I use gitlab to run unit tests each time someone push the code. I get this error during composer installation.

```
> Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters
Creating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache


  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                              
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  



  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]        
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  



  [PDOException]                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  


Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception
```

Here is my configuration :

.gitlab-ci.yml file

```
    # Select image from https://hub.docker.com/_/php/
    image: php:5.6

    # Select what we should cache
    cache:
      paths:
      - vendor/

    before_script:
    # Install ssh-agent if not already installed, it is required by Docker.
    # (change apt-get to yum if you use a CentOS-based image)
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'

    #

 Run ssh-agent (inside the build environment)
- eval $(ssh-agent -s)

# Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
- ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")

# For Docker builds disable host key checking. Be aware that by adding that
# you are suspectible to man-in-the-middle attacks.
# WARNING: Use this only with the Docker executor, if you use it with shell
# you will overwrite your user's SSH config.
- mkdir -p ~/.ssh
- '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

- cp ci/custom.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
- bash ci/docker_install.sh > /dev/null

# Install composer
- curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

services:
- mysql:latest

variables:
  # Configure mysql service (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)
  MYSQL_DATABASE: symfony
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

# We test PHP5.6 (the default) with MySQL
test:mysql:
  script:
  # Install all project dependencies
  - php composer.phar install
  - phpunit --coverage-text --colors=never -c app/
```

parameters.yml.dist

```
parameters:
    database_host:     127.0.0.1
    database_port:     ~
    database_name:     symfony
    database_user:     root
    database_password: root

    mailer_transport:  smtp
    mailer_host:       127.0.0.1
    mailer_user:       ~
    mailer_password:   ~

    # A secret key that's used to generate certain security-related tokens
    secret:            ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt

    database_slave1_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_slave1_port: ~
    database_slave1_name: symfony
    database_slave1_user: root
    database_slave1_password: root
```

I have read and follow the instruction of the gitlab website. Maybe my mistake is obvious, but I can't see it.

Comment: Is a MySQL server installed?

Comment: MySQL should be installed as a service (services:
- mysql:latest) 
I have configured the password (MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root) and the default user is root.

Comment: Hi @barden, I'm facing the same problem but I think my conf is not good, can you share your docker_install.sh ? TY

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you are using MySQL that is running in another container, you have to use its hostname, not *127.0.0.1*. **The correct database host should be "mysql"**. This is covered in [one of the sections](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#how-is-service-linked-to-the-build) of the GitLab's documentation:

> The service container for MySQL will be accessible under the hostname mysql. So, in order to access your database service you have to connect to the host named mysql instead of a socket or localhost.

Comment: Whatttttttt wow can't believe this got me 6 hours :/ Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

One of the possible reasons for this error is that you attempt to access the database while it is still initialising. This is covered in the MySQL's [caveats](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) section on the Docker HUB.

> If there is no database initialised when the container starts, then a default database will be created. While this is the expected behaviour, this means that it will not accept incoming connections until such initialisation completes. This may cause issues when using automation tools...

A **crude solution** would be to use `sleep` command before you start any process that accesses database. You can add it to the `before_script` section:

```
before_script:
  - sleep 30s
```

A **better solution** would be to probe the MySQL server, repeatedly checking whether it already accepts connections.

Comment: Thanks. That helped. It's weird how (in my case) it just stopped working without any changes to the pipeline.